# Desktop responsive scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, plugins

My website competitionmantra.com works fine on mobile while scrolling down.
But, on desktop it does not scroll.

Here are two screenshots of it.

[image: Desktop website which doesn't scroll]

[image: Mobile viewport in browser which is scrolling down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I can scroll when all the JavaScript eventually loads it prevents the scroll so I assume its to do with one of those JS files you have implemented, which there are an insane amount of by the way!
Easy fix is the adding:

```
height:100%;
```

to the body tag in the CSS

Comment: The issue is comes back again.

Answer (score 0):

I added height:100% onto your body and it worked